# Running a python program which runs a SHELL script containg linux based command inside a windows base image docker

Tags: linux, windows, shell, docker, docker-for-windows

I want to run a SHELL SCRIPT file inside the windows base docker image. How to build a windows based docker image which has the functionality of running Linux scripts and supports Linux-based commands?

Answer (score 0):

*Simply spoken:* ADD a Cygwin container to your windows application's docker setup.

*But:* Depending on what tools your specific shell script requires your mileage may vary (hard to say without having seen the script).

*Maybe:* Depending on how complex the task of that shell script is, it *could* be easier to reimplement the script using Windows tools (e.g. using Batch- or PowerShell commands).